# replace a string containing a substring with a string in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I need to replace a string containing a substring with another string. For example:

```
biography -> biography
biographical -> biography
biopic -> biography
bio-pic -> biography-pic
I watched a biographical movie -> I watched a biography movie
```

Here, all words on the left contain `bio`, so the whole word is replaced by `biography`. I am aware of `string.replace()` function, but it doesn't seem to work well here. I looked up regular expressions, but I'm not sure if `re` is the right library to solve the problem.

Comment: try - `if 'bio' in word: word = 'biography'`

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas which maps `bio-pic` to `biography` rather than `biography-pic`

Comment: `doesn't seem to work well here`? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @JohnColeman `bio-pic` would be one word without spaces i assume. In would check if it finds the substring

Comment: @SukumarRdjf Good question, I suspect that the problem is that it maps `biography` to `biographygraphy`

Comment: I've edited the question - added one more example. It may be a sentence, not just one word

Comment: First split string to words then apply suggestion of @SubhrajyotiDas to each word.

Comment: @Sukumar-Rdjf I mean that I don't want to construct the dictionary consisting of all possible words containing `bio`, and then call `string.replace(word, bio)` for every such word

Comment: Are you certain that you won't have things like `'biology'` which have nothing to do with `'biography'` but nevertheless contain `'bio'`?

Comment: Is there any chance that the words in your sentence can have any special characters other than `-`?

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, I'm certain. I have a list of genres for movies.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don't really want to do that because I have some other replacements - like `romantic comedy -> romcom`

Comment: what about this input - "I watched a bio movie with Martin Rubio", is it ok for it to become "I watched a biography movie with Martin Rubiography"?
If not, you might have to change the approach (dictionary-based approach, use NLP tools or so).
You might be surprised on how complex it can get if you get natural language as an input, to replace "u" with "you" on the right context of slang text I had to train a ML model.

Comment: @diplodoc I am sorry, I mean "I watched a biography movie with Martin biography"
I am not talking about a list, but rather on how you apply it on a sentence.

Comment: @Maayao I've already resolved the problem using the approach presented by DarryIG. I had to transform a list of movie genres into a general form.

Comment: @diplodoc So if you can, it will be nice if you will clarify it by editing the question, saying you want to transform a list - so it won't be misleading for people reading it in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex

```
import re

s = """
biography -> biography
biographical -> biography
biopic -> biography
bio-pic -> biography-pic
I watched a biographical movie -> I watched a biography movie
"""
x = re.sub(r'\b(bio\w*)', 'biography', s)
print(x)
```

**Output**

```
biography -> biography
biography -> biography
biography -> biography
biography-pic -> biography-pic
I watched a biography movie -> I watched a biography movie
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

search_string = 'bio'
replace_string = 'biography'
vals = ['biography', 'biographical', 'biopic', 'bio-pic', 'something else', 'bio pic', 'I watched a biographical movie']
altered = [re.sub(re.escape(search_string)+r'\w*',replace_string,val) for val in vals]
print(altered)
```

outputs

```
['biography', 'biography', 'biography', 'biography-pic', 'something else', 'biography pic', 'I watched a biography movie']
```

For the regex part, `re.escape()` can be used to turn a variable into a regular expression. I assumed your `'bio'` search string will not be constant. The rest of it `\w*` means to match 0 or more (the `*`) of the preceding character. `\w` means word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _). Since we're only matching word characters, it stops the match when a space is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expression to solve this problem. It will definitely. You can change regular expression according to your requirement. Here is an example code

```
import re
s = "biography biographical biopic bio-pic I watched a biographical movie"
replaced = re.sub('(bio[A-Za-z]*)', 'biography', s)
print (replaced )
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the decisions:

```
import re

def f(s, pat, replace):
    pat = r'(\w*%s\w*)' % pat
    return re.sub(pat, "biography", s)

input = """
biography -> biography
biographical -> biography
biopic -> biography
bio-pic -> biography-pic
I watched a biographical movie -> I watched a biography movie
"""

c = f(input, "bio", "biography")
print(c)
```

Output:

```
biography -> biography
biography -> biography
biography -> biography
biography-pic -> biography-pic
I watched a biography movie -> I watched a biography movie
```